# Converting keys of hash into camelcase

Tags: ruby

`hash = {test_user: '1', user_details: {first_name: "Test"}}`

`output = {testUser: '1', userDetails: {firstName: "Test"}}`

Program:

```
  new_hash = {}
  if hash.values.map{|x| x.class}.include?(Hash)
    hash.each do |k,v|
      if v.class == Hash
        new_hash[k.to_s.upcase] = hash.transform_keys{ |key| key.to_s.upcase }
      else
        new_hash[k.to_s.upcase] = v
      end
    end
   puts new_hash
  end
```

It is giving output like this:

```
{"TEST_USER"=>"1", "USER_DETAILS"=>{"TEST_USER"=>"1", "USER_DETAILS"=>{:first_name=>"Test"}}}
```

Can someone help me to get correct output.

Comment: Rails comes with a [`camelize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize) method: `"test_user".camelize(:lower)` gives `"testUser"`.

Comment: @Stefan I have tried using camelize but giving me error like this: undefined method `camelize' for "test_user":String

Comment: That's odd – what version of Rails are you running?

Comment: @Stefan, I am using ruby for writing this program.

Comment: You should update your question then, it is tagged with `ruby-on-rails` :)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby on Rails has a built-in method to transform keys in deeply nested hashes.

You can use that [`Hash#deep_transform_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_transform_keys) in combination with [`String#camelize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize) like this:

```
hash = { test_user: '1', user_details: { first_name: "Test" }}

hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.camelize(:lower).to_sym }
#=> { :testUser => "1", :userDetails => { :firstName=>"Test" }}
```

Note that you need to translate the symbolized key to string with `to_s` before calling `camelize` and with `to_sym` back to symbol.

Answer (score 1):

For ruby you can do something like this

```rb
def camelize_hash(hash)
  new_hash = {}

  hash.each do |key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash[camelize_str(key).to_sym] = camelize_hash(value)
    else
      new_hash[camelize_str(key).to_sym] = value
    end
  end

  new_hash
end

def camelize_str(str)
  str.to_s.gsub(/_([a-z0-9])/) {  Regexp.last_match[1].upcase }
end

hash = {test_user: '1', user_details: {first_name: "Test"}}
new_hash = camelize_hash(hash)
```

**Update:**

`camelize` method is for Rails and is not available in plain Ruby.

Comment: I am new to ruby. How can I call this method in terminal?
ruby test.rb. but it is not returning any values.

Comment: Rehma, Please help.

Comment: @KumarNikhil you can add these methods In your test.rb file and then call them like `camelize_hash(hash)` will return the new hash with camelized keys.

Comment: I've updated the code to include how to call this in the `test.rb` file.